# Populating TextViews with Parse backend

Tags: java, android, parsing, pfquery

I am hosting a Parse server that holds data containing plants. I have no errors in my code but it doesn't seem to fetch any data. I want the query to equal the contents of 'name'. For example if 'name' contains "Daisy" it will find the data for that flower and display the selected information. Here is my code:

```
public class mygardenDetail extends Activity {

String name;
String kgsays;
String care;
String tips;
String image;
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
List<ParseObject> ob;
private List<PlantListitems> plantlist = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.mygarden_detail);


Intent i = getIntent();
name = i.getStringExtra("name");



// Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml

TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
TextView txtKGsays = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.KGsays);
TextView txtCare = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Care);
TextView txtTips = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tips);

// Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
ImageView imgflag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
txtName.setText(name);


// Capture position and set results to the ImageView
// Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
   imageLoader.DisplayImage(image, imgflag);



    try {
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery<>("Plants2");
    query.whereMatches("plantName", String.valueOf(equals(name)));
    ob = query.find();

    for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                // Locate images in flag column
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("image");

                //PlantListitems map = new PlantListitems();
                txtKGsays.setText((String) country.get("KGsays"));
                txtCare.setText((String) country.get("Care"));
                txtTips.setText((String) country.get("tips"));
                //imgflag.DisplayImage(image.getUrl());
                //plantlist.add(map);
            }
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
        }
```

Comment: whats is happening right now? unclear question.

Comment: what is happening now? Well like i said its showing no errors but is not fetching any data from the backend and displaying it in the textviews

Comment: have you checked answer?

Comment: I have thank you, although still no success

Comment: whats happening? could you please clear your question in detail.

Comment: its not fetching the data from parse and displaying it in the textviews

Comment: did you check value exist on manually in database?

Comment: Yes I have, I worked out the fix: I replaced the line in your code: query.whereMatches("plantName", String.valueOf(equals(name)));          With: query.whereEqualTo("plantName", (name));

Comment: I just need to work out how to get and set the image now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findInBackground()` with callback

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery<>("Plants2");
query.whereEqualTo("plantName", (name));
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
public void done(List<ParseObject> listCountry, ParseException e) {
   for (ParseObject country : listCountry) {
            // Locate images in flag column
            ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("image");

            //PlantListitems map = new PlantListitems();
            txtKGsays.setText((String) country.get("KGsays"));
            txtCare.setText((String) country.get("Care"));
            txtTips.setText((String) country.get("tips"));
            //imgflag.DisplayImage(image.getUrl());
            //plantlist.add(map);
        }
}
});
```